# Is possible to access Game Center, directly from a custom keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I need to authenticate the user in Game Center from my custom keyboard, [according to apple docs it should be done:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html) "Via containing app, keyboard can participate in Game Center and In-App Purchase"

I can reach game center from my keyboard extension, but it complains that the bundle is not correct, because it add a d com.xxx.yyy.keyboard instead of com.xxx.yyy.

The only way to do the auth is in the containing app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can present `Game Center Controller` from a keyboard extension due to its restrictions.

Moreover, you have to be aware that `Game Center` will not be part of `iOS 10` and will probably disappear soon. You will have to design your own interface using `GameKit` data.

Comment: Yes, I know that Apple will remove the `Game Center App`
I'm implementing it in the `containing App` in the case the user is not logged.